# redirected request when exception throwed

Tags: java, exception, redirect, spring-mvc, aspects

in my application (using spring),

i try to call a method from view using spring exposingBean. and when i try to invoke a method from view, it throw error. i try to catch  with HandlerExceptionResolver, but no luck, i think it cannot handled by HandlerExceptionResolver because exception wasn't thrown to controller.

so i try another way to redirect the request when exception thrown. and i think aspect has possibility to do it. is it possible to redirected request when exception thrown from aspect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you rightly say, `HandlerExceptionResolver` will not be invoked when an exception is thrown from inside the view. These resolvers are very specifically targetted at controller exceptions.

Your best options here are to use either a `HandlerInterceptor` and override the `afterCompletion` method, which will contain the exception thrown by the view. You *may* be able to send a redirect from here, dependning on whether or not the response has already been committed by the view.

I don't see how aspects would help you here, either. Not the tool for this job.

However, my advice to you is to stop using exposed bean in your JSP. I realise that it's temptingly convenient, but this is the sort of trouble you get from using it.  I advise that your controller assemble all the data required by the view, stick it in the model, and send it to the view. That way, there's less danger of the view triggering an exception, since it already has everything it needs.

Also, if you need to send a redirect, as you do, then you really need to do this *before* the view starts executing. Otherwise, the view layer may start writing out the HTTP response headers *before* the exception is thrown. If this happens, then you won't then be able to send a redirect instead - the response is "committed".

Comment: +1 - views should be doing things that are likely to throw exceptions.

Comment: @Stephen: I think you missed out a "not" in there somewhere :)

Comment: yes i agree with you, i realize that exposed bean is out of spring scoped. and its danger. but i still have no idea how to bind data to model and it will be used in several view. any suggestion? btw, thanks for your answer.